# Right way of catching NO_DATA_FOUND exception after opening a cursor in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I have two ways for catching NO_DATA_FOUND exception (the second way don't catch an exception properly...)

**First way**

```
create or replace package body pkg_mnt_departments is
  procedure p_get_data(ls_cursor out sys_refcursor) is
  begin

    begin
      open ls_cursor for
        select field1, field2 from mytable
          where 1 = 2;
    exception
      when others then
        dbms_output.put_line('Exception');
    end;
  end p_get_data;
end pkg_mnt_departments;
```

**Second way**

```
procedure get_data(id  in number,
                   l_cursor out sys_refcursor)
  is

  begin

    if (condition1) then
        open l_cursor for
               select field1, field2
                 from mytable
                where fieldid = id;

        fetch l_cursor into v_field1, v_field2;

        if(v_field1 is null) then
            --Execute sentences when cursor is empty
        end if;
    end if;

end;
```

I would like what's of these ways is the correct. The first way doesn't work but the second do...But I would like if I'm doing the right thing.

PD: For some cases the second way didn't work...I executed the query outside of procedure and returned rows but when it was executed by procedure don't...I don't know if the fact of have indexed field(fieldid) has influenced.
Thanks for help me :)

**UPDATE**

I did some changes in my procedure:

procedure get_data(id  in number,
                       l_cursor out sys_refcursor)
      is

```
  begin

    if (condition1) then
        open l_cursor for
               select field1, field2
                 from mytable
                where fieldid = id;

        fetch l_cursor into v_field1, v_field2;

        if(l_cursor%rowcount = 0) then
            --Execute sentences when cursor is empty
        end if;
    end if;

end;
```

But, Neither works...By some strange reason cursor didn't return data...My final solution was leaving to use cursors...Results were returned at another way

Comment: When doesn't the first method work?

Comment: I'm trying of catching no_data_found exception and the first way doesn't work for that...

Comment: @CesarMiguel. I've extend my answer with a little more detail. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

The `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception is only raised when a `SELECT ... INTO ...` clause return no rows. It won't be raised when you use an explicit cursor and a `FETCH` statement.

I think in general, it's a matter of style/preference as to whether you use implicit or explicit cursors. I'm not really a developer, so others may wish to comment here. But an implicity cursor is expected to fetch 0 or 1 row. If it fetches 0, then you get NO_DATA_FOUND.
Explicit cursors are meant for 0 to many rows. So you generally will open the cursor inside a loop where you will FETCH into variables. In theis case, you are testing for the "End Of Fetch". There is a cusror variable that you can use to test for this - %NOTFOUND. This is used for exiting the loop, something like

```
open c1
LOOP
  fetch c1 into var;
  exit when c1%notfound;
  -- do stuff
END LOOP;
close c1;
```

Comment: In this case what's the right way for detecting an empty cursor (after of my sentence `open ls_cursor for`...)

Comment: you can't check after open statement but you can check after fetch statement, like if l_cursor%rowcount = 0

Comment: @CesarMiguel if you're returning a ref cursor then it's not the procedure that needs to handle the case where there are no rows in the cursor; it's whatever code is calling your procedure that needs to handle it. It doesn't make sense for you to open a ref cursor and fetch a row from it and only then pass it back to the calling code; that calling code will no longer be able to see the row that you fetched (and what if that was the only row in the resultset?).

Comment: @Bobc `But an implicit cursor is expected to fetch 0 or 1 row` - I would argue that that an implicit cursor is expected to fetch 1 row. If it fetches 0 or more than one row, it will error (no_data_found or too_many_rows, respectively).

Answer (score 1):

I am creating a Procedure which have a cursor to retrieve data from SALES table. If Cursor - sales_cursor, does not get any data, this is how you raise NO_DATA_FOUND.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FETCH_SALES (O_ID IN NUMBER, L_TOTALROWS OUT
NUMBER)
AS
CURSOR C IS SELECT * FROM SALES WHERE ORDER_ID=O_ID;
REC SALES%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
OPEN C;

LOOP

FETCH C INTO REC;

IF(C%ROWCOUNT = 0) THEN
RAISE NO_DATA_FOUND;
EXIT;
END IF;
IF C%NOTFOUND THEN
  
EXIT;
END IF;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(REC.SALES_AMOUNT);
END LOOP;
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO L_TOTALROWS FROM SALES
WHERE SALES_DATE = rec.sales_date;
EXCEPTION
 WHEN no_data_found THEN
 dbms_output.put_line('No such Order!');
 WHEN too_many_rows THEN
 dbms_output.put_line('You got more than 1 row!');
 WHEN others THEN
 dbms_output.put_line('Error!');
END;

DECLARE
 TOTAL_ROWS NUMBER;
BEGIN
 FETCH_SALES (1267, TOTAL_ROWS);
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Total Number of rows: ' || TOTAL_ROWS);
END;
```

Comment: that ran like a charm. nice approach. thanks!